# Guessing Loop Stuck Java

Tags: java, loops

I'm making a program for an assignment where I have to let the user guess 3 numbers of a lock to unlock it. If they can't do it within 3 guesses its game over. Simple enough, and as far as I can tell, I'm doing it right, so don't know where I'm going wrong. Here is the section of code:

```
do{
    try{
        String g1Str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number 1:");
        g1 = Integer.parseInt(g1Str);
        looper = 2;
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Not a Number");
        looper = 1;
    }
    if(g1!=num1){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect guess, try again");
        lives = lives - 1;
        looper = 1;
    }
    else if(g1==num1){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct!");
        looper = 2;
    }
}while(looper==1||lives!=0);
```

Here is my thinking: Ask the user to enter the number, attempt to convert the string to an integer. I use a try catch, to ensure that the user really did enter a number and not a letter. After, I see if the guess equals the real number. If it doesn't, you loose a life (lives were declared as 3 earlier), then set looper to 1 so you can try and guess again if you have enough lives. If its right, the looper is set to 2, and the loop is broken, at which point the user can guess the second number. I only want the loop to stay active as long as you have enough lives, so I set the "while" statement to when looper is 1, OR when lives don't equal 0. But it doesn't seem to break the loop if lives go down to 0. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change the logic of of your while loop:

`while (looper == 1 && lives != 0)`

Right now, if you have more lives, it'll keep looping, no matter what looper is.

Comment: @DoanCuong Why is it a better solution?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I didn't though it through

Comment: Okay, I see whats wrong now, I was under the assumption that OR meant that if either of them were wrong it would break. Fixed now, and I added `if(lives==0){ looper=2}` at the beginning of the other loops. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want the boolean AND `&&` rather than OR `||`, like so:

```
while(looper==1 && lives!=0);
```

`||` evaluates to `true` if either one of its arguments is true, so what you have will keep going if `looper` is `1`, regardless of what `lives` is. Likewise, your code will keep looping if `lives` is not `0`, even if you set `looper` to `2`.

`&&` will evaluate to `true` only if both conditions are true, and will give `false` and exit the loop if either `looper` is not `1` or `lives` is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
if(g1!=num1){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect guess, try again");
      lives = lives - 1;
      looper = 1;
   }
```

By this

```
if(g1!=num1){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect guess, try again");
   lives = lives - 1;
   if(lives == 0)
   {
       looper = 2;
   }
   else
   {
       looper = 1;
   }

}
```

Because when your `lives` reach 0. `looper` still equal to 1 so the loop continue